# Hibernate can not create table

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, logging

i am writing a simple code to test hibernate which contains main class,a model class and hibernate configuration file.but my log gets stuck after printing line

```
**Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_DETAIL**
```

**Model class:**

```
    package com.test.hibernate.koushik;


import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAIL")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName + " From getter";
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


}
```

**main class:**

```
package com.test.hibernate.koushik;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserDetails userdetail = new UserDetails();
        userdetail.setUserName("Hemkar");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(userdetail);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

    }

}
```

**configuration xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

      <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->
        <mapping class="com.test.hibernate.koushik.UserDetails"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**log:**

```
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:27 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db]
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:29 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mar 19, 2015 12:32:30 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_DETAIL
```

what is the reason that this application is not able to create table.

Answer (score 1):

First check if you already have this table into your database, if you do, try to delete manual and run again your code if doesn't work, try to do this way.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Test">

    <class>test.UserDetail</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//..."/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**EntityManagerUtil.java**
    package test;

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class EntityManagerUtil {

private static EntityManagerFactory factory = null;
private static EntityManager em = null;

public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    if (factory == null) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test");
    }

    if (em == null){
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    return em;
}
```

}

**Main.java**

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserDetail userdetail = new UserDetail();
        userdetail.setUserName("zzzz");

        EntityManager em = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(userdetail);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        System.out.println("insert with success");

    }

}
```